# How to create HTML tags (with content) on the fly with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, children

I am trying to convert this HTML code to be generated by Javascript on the fly for live data.

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ive found a few methods like: appendChild, getElementById, innerHTML and so on. Here is what I've tried so far. I can't seem to get the data to show up.

```
                               stringy = data2.Items[0].groupName.values[i];
                               var para = document.createElement("div");
                               var node = document.createTextNode(stringy);
                               para.appendChild(node);
                               var element = document.getElementById("parental");
                               element.appendChild(para);

                               //create div and give it a class
                                para.setAttribute('class', 'dropbtn');
                                var div = document.createElement("div");
                                div.setAttribute('class', 'dropdown-content');
                                para.parentNode.insertBefore(div, para.nextSibling);
                    //create link tags and give them text
                                var alinky = document.createElement("a");
                                alinky.setAttribute('id', 'linky');
                                document.getElementById('linky').innerHTML = "linky poo"
                                div.appendChild(alinky);
```

Hopefully someone could fill in the blanks on getting this HTML code to be reproduced with javascript. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I am trying to create a dropdown menu like this:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown_hover

However, I am trying to create multiple dropdown menus, that dynamically change in quantity based on a query to DynamoDB (AWS). therefore I am using javascript to create the html tags.

The problem is that the scope of the query function does not allow me to see the data outside of the query function, or even inject data into it.

For example, if I try to get a button description from the query, and write to it `descriptionArray[0] = data2.Items[0].description;` so that I can append the button to the dropdown div, it doesn't know which iteration I'm on in the for loop due to scope. In this example, `descriptionArray[0]` will work, but `descriptionArray[i]` will not work because the for loop is outside the query.

Here is the entire logic:

```
                        //group data   
                        var length =  data2.Items[0].groupName.values.length;
                        // create elements
                        const dpdown1 = document.createElement('div');
                        // set dpdown1 class
                        dpdown1.setAttribute('class', 'dropdown');
                        console.log(dpdown1); 

                        var button = new Array();
                        var dpdown2 = new Array();   
                        var membersArray = new Array();
                        var descriptionArray = new Array(); 
                        var linksArray = new Array();
                        var stringy = new Array; 

                            //list groups
                            for(i = 0; i<length; i++){
                                // create button, set button attribs
                                button[i] = document.createElement('button');
                                button[i].setAttribute('class','dropbtn');
                                //create dropdown div, set attributes
                                dpdown2[i] = document.createElement('div');
                                dpdown2[i].setAttribute('class', 'dropdown-content');

                                //list of group names
                                stringy[i] = data2.Items[0].groupName.values[i];
                                var stringyy = stringy[i];
                                var desc;
                                //query group members and description                        
                                var docClient1 = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ region: AWS.config.region });
                                var identityId = AWS.config.credentials.identityId;
                                var paramsyy = {
                                    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                                        ":v1": stringyy
                                    },
                                    KeyConditionExpression: "groupName = :v1",
                                    TableName: "group"
                                };
                                docClient1.query(paramsyy, function(err, data2) {
                                    if (err) {
                                        console.error(err);
                                    }else{

                                        descriptionArray[0] = data2.Items[0].description;
                                        //traverse members
                                        for(k = 0; k<data2.Items[0].members.values.length; k++){
                                          // create dropdown links of members
                                          membersArray[k] = data2.Items[0].members.values[k];
                                          linksArray[k] = document.createElement('a');
                                          linksArray[k].setAttribute('href', '#')
                                          linksArray[k].innerText = membersArray[k];

                                          // nest into dpdown2 div, set dpdown2 attribs
                                          dpdown2[0].appendChild(linksArray[k]);

                                        }     
                                    }          
                                });

                                button[i].innerText = stringyy + ": " + descriptionArray[0];

                                // nest into dpdown1
                                dpdown1.appendChild(button[i]);
                                dpdown1.appendChild(dpdown2[i]);
                            }
                            // append to DOM
                            const target = document.getElementById('target');
                            target.appendChild(dpdown1);
```

if I use the I from the first for loop inside the query function, it will give me undefined results.

Comment: Is your element with ID `parental` in the page? It is not in the HTML snippet that you provided.

Comment: yes sorry it is embedded in the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's how you can do it with vanilla JavaScipt, there are multiple ways to do it, but this way only uses 4 methods: `createElement`, `setAttribute`, `appendChild`, and `getElementById`, and directly sets 1 property: `innerText`.

```js
// create elements
const dpdown1 = document.createElement('div');
const button = document.createElement('button');
const dpdown2 = document.createElement('div');
const link1 = document.createElement('a');
const link2 = document.createElement('a');
const link3 = document.createElement('a');

// set link attribs
link1.setAttribute('href', '#')
link1.innerText = 'Link 1';
link2.setAttribute('href', '#')
link2.innerText = 'Link 2';
link3.setAttribute('href', '#')
link3.innerText = 'Link 3';

// nest into dpdown2, set dpdown2 attribs
dpdown2.appendChild(link1);
dpdown2.appendChild(link2);
dpdown2.appendChild(link3);
dpdown2.setAttribute('class', 'dropdown-content');

// set button attribs
button.setAttribute('class','dropbtn');
button.innerText = "Dropdown"

// nest into dpdown1
dpdown1.appendChild(button);
dpdown1.appendChild(dpdown2);

// set dpdown1 class
dpdown1.setAttribute('class', 'dropdown');

// append to DOM
const target = document.getElementById('target');
target.appendChild(dpdown1);
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

You will to append it to something, in this example it's `<div id="target"></div>` but it could be something else.

Happy coding!

Comment: thanks you for your help! I am having trouble using your code in a for loop. any way you can have a look?

Answer (score 1):

Mainly you are just doing things out of order.

1. Create the `.dropdown <div>` with its class.
2. Complete the `.dropbtn <button>` with its class and text.
3. Add the button to the div.
4. Create the `.dropdown-content <div>`.
5. Complete each link with its `href` attribute and text.
6. Add each link to the `.dropdown-content <div>`.
7. Add the `.dropdown-content` div to the `.dropdown <div>`.
8. Find the parent element in the document.
9. Append the whole complete `.dropdown <div>` to the document.

```js
var para = document.createElement("div"); //make .dropdown div
para.setAttribute('class', 'dropdown'); //add .dropdown class to div
var button = document.createElement("button"); //create button
button.setAttribute('class', 'dropbtn'); //add .dropbtn class to button
var node = document.createTextNode('Dropdown'); //create button text
button.appendChild(node); //add text to button
para.appendChild(button); //add button to .dropdown div

var div = document.createElement("div"); //create .dropdown-content div
div.setAttribute('class', 'dropdown-content'); //add .dropdown-content class to div

//repeat for all necessary links
var alinky = document.createElement("a"); //creat link
alinky.setAttribute('href', '#'); //set link href attribute
var alinkyText = document.createTextNode("Link 1"); //create text for link
alinky.appendChild(alinkyText); //add text to link
div.appendChild(alinky); //add link to dropdown div

para.appendChild(div); //add .dropdown-content div to .dropdown div

var element = document.getElementById("parental"); //find parent element
element.parentNode.insertBefore(para, element.nextSibling); //add .dropdown div to the bottom of the parent element
```

```html
<div id="parental">

</div>
```

Comment: thanks, any ideas on how to do it with a query/for loop?

Comment: @FlightHoldings If you wish to execute similar code in a for loop, I would suggest storing the values that you need into an array of objects and altering the code to input the values where you need them.

Comment: awesome, yeah i did that with string interpolation for the names of the tags/elements